# Python - Traverse lexical tree finding words in lexicon

Tags: python, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

Suppose we've got a tree structure where each node has 3 attributes: token, children, entries/ids.

A visualized example of the tree (tokens) could look like this:
[image]

**Task**: Given a context window, for example,

```
['take', 'a', 'long', 'bath', 'after', 'my', 'flight']
```

I'd like to generate all possible candidates relating to the **first token** `take`, which are

```
[(take, a, bath), (take, after), (take, flight)]
```

Note that, the following code is positioned to handle early stopping, see example 1, `comic book` and `comic book art`

```
diff = len(node.entries) - len(node.children)
if diff == 1 and node.children != {}:
```

**What I've done**:

```
def traverse(self, tokens, node, tokens_matched):
    diff = len(node.entries) - len(node.children)
    if diff == 1 and node.children != {}:
        yield tokens_matched
    if node.children == {}:
        yield tokens_matched

    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        if tokens[i] in node.children.keys():
            tokens_matched += (tokens[i],)
            new_tokens = tokens[i+1:]
            new_node = node.children[tokens[i]]
            yield from self.traverse(new_tokens, new_node, tokens_matched)



def generate_candidates(self, tokens):
    node = self.root

    results = []
    if tokens[0] in node.children.keys():
        new_node = node.children[tokens[0]]
        for i in range(1,len(tokens)):
            tokens_matched = (tokens[0],)
            new_tokens = tokens[i:]
            results.extend(list(iself.traverse(new_tokens, new_node, tokens_matched)))

    return results
```

*Example 1*: `tokens = ['comic', 'book', 'art', 'on', 'the', 'web']` and outputs of my algorithm (the output is correct)

```
[('comic', 'book'), ('comic', 'book', 'art')]
```

*Example 2*: Given `tokens = ['write', 'a', 'review', 'about','my','book']` and outputs of my algorithm (the output is incorrect, correct output should be `[('write', 'a', 'book'),('write', 'about'), ('write', 'book')]`)

```
[('write', 'a', 'book'), ('write', 'a', 'about'), ('write', 'a', 'about', 'book'),\
('write', 'about'), ('write', 'about', 'book'), ('write', 'about'), ('write', 'about', 'book'),\
('write', 'book'), ('write', 'book')]
```

example 2 doesn't return the correct answer, very likely it's because I mis-handled some recursions, not sure where it happened exactly. Also, if you have any suggestion to boost the speed, please feel free to comment.

**Edited**

Solved the issue, the updates

```
def traverse(self, tokens, node, tokens_matched):
    diff = len(node.entries) - len(node.children)
    if diff == 1 and node.children != {}:
        yield tokens_matched
    if node.children == {}:
        yield tokens_matched

    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        if tokens[i] in node.children.keys():
            tokens_matched += (tokens[i],)
            new_tokens = tokens[i+1:]
            current_token = node.token
            if current_token != tokens_matched[-2]:
                to_list = list(tokens_matched)
                to_list.pop(-2)
                tokens_matched = tuple(to_list)
            new_node = node.children[tokens[i]]
            yield from self.traverse(new_tokens, new_node, tokens_matched)

def generate_candidates(self, tokens):
    node = self.root

    tokens = tokens[0:min(len(tokens), self.MAX_GAP)]
    candidates = []
    if tokens[0] in node.children.keys():
        new_node = node.children[tokens[0]]
        tokens_matched = (tokens[0],)
        new_tokens = tokens[1:]
        candidates.extend(list(self.traverse(new_tokens, new_node, tokens_matched)))

    # ne generator
    candidates = CandidatesGenerator.ne_generator(tokens, candidates, ne_size=ne_size)

    return candidates
```

Got one question left, any idea on how to shorten execution time for the task? This is quite important, as this snippet would be executed millions of times, I'd like to optimize it as much as possible (still within the scope of Python).